# Gitlab pipeline running in VM and not in Gitlab server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab server from the company where the project and the pipeline are configured. By default, every time a commit is done, the pipeline starts to execute in the Gitlab server.

I have my personalized VM, which is completely different from Gitlab. I want that the pipeline will be executed in my personalized VM instead of the Gitlab server. What should I do so that the pipeline runs on the VM and not on the Gitlab server?

I have configured the following runner in `config.toml` that is located in `$MYPROJECT/`:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Project-name"
  url = "https://gitlab.server/"
  token = "TOKEN ID"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "bash"
```

There are things that I don't understand.

1. If I want to execute the pipeline in my personalized VM, should I install Gitlab runner in the VM [1]?
2. Should I have the project source code in the VM so that it can read the `config.toml` file every time there is a commit?
3. If I register the runner with the token key in the Gitlab server, how the Gitlab server knows that the pipeline is to be executed in the VM and not in the server [2]?
4. Should I use the executor `docker` or `shell`, to execute the pipeline in the VM?

[1] https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html

[2] https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#registering-runners

Comment: Hi there! Your question currently contains 5 questions in the same post. Due to this your question may be [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). If you can, edit the post so it asks the core problem, otherwise ask just a single question here and add new posts for the other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For running a job on a machine you need a GitLab Runner installed on that machine, connected with the GitLab server.
2. The project source code is fetched automatically in front of every run
3. You can use a tag (e.g. "MyVM") when registering the runner. Then you can set the same tag into your job so that this job is only executed by this runner. See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#use-tags-to-control-which-jobs-a-runner-can-run
4. You need to use `docker` if you want to use docker in your VM (which needs to be installed before there). Otherwise use `shell`.